# Error with lm() command: invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: r, lm

I'm taking a class on R and I cannot get the professor's code to work. I am trying to do a simple linear model and I run this code:

```
ozone <- read.table(
    "http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/ozone.csv",
    sep = ",",
    header = TRUE
)

fit = lm(ozone ~ ., data = ozone)
summary(fit)
```

Which keeps giving me the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = ozone ~ ., data = ozone, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'ozone

It's really depressing as they are the first two lines of code in his lecture notes. I have also found several other forum posts on this topic (it's even listed as a common R mistake), but I am too special to figure out how to change it.

I tried reading it as a `numeric`, and as a `data.frame`, which is what most other threads suggested, but neither worked.

Comment: Please do not add the same question on several sites. Your question was answered already on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70990/error-with-lm-common-r-mistake)

Comment: Professors are always wrong.  You haven't learned that yet?  :-)  (says a double-faculty brat)

Comment: Here's a crazy idea:  Ask the professor.

Answer (score 5):

ozone table doesnt have ozone as a variable and hence your lm function would fail

```
ozone<-read.table("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/ozone.csv", sep=",", header=T)
fit = lm(Av8top ~.,data=as.data.frame(ozone))
summary(fit)
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your ozone data set contains X (explanatory values) in column 5,6, and 7.  Simply save these into a matrix data type like `ozone.X = as.matrix(cbind(ozone[5],ozone[6],ozone[7]))`.  Do the same for your Y column.  If it's in column 2 of ozone do `ozone.Y = as.matrix(ozone[2])`.  Now you can run your `lm` function without it barking about a type error, `lm(ozone.Y ~ ozone.X)`.